# JSF + DDD : É correto usar as entidades de dominio dentro do managed bean?

Tags: jsf, cdi, ddd, ioc, domínio

1 - No DDD é correto deixar os objetos de dominio serem alimentados pelo JSF através de EL ?

```
   // classe da camada de dominio
   public class Cliente {
       private String nome;
       // getters e setters;
    }

   // bean ligado diretamente ao objeto de dominio
    #{bean.cliente.nome}
```

Pergunto pq no ASP o pessoal usa o VM pra alimentar as entradas do usuário e o automapper pra converter os dados da VM num objeto de dominio.

2 - Se isso é permitido, no caso de eu usar o CDI, devo injetar essas classes logo em cima no managedBeans ou a instância dela tem q vir de dentro da camada de dominio ( uma classes de serviço, por exemplo )?

```
// usando cdi para injetar
@named
class Bean{

     @inject
     Cliente cliente;
}
```

ou

```
@named
class Bean{

     Cliente cliente;

     Bean(){
        cliente = servico.getInstanciaCliente();
     }
}
```

Comment: Gostei da pergunta, eu também acho muito feio de expor minhas entidades de domínio na view, sei que a maioria das aplicações com faces + CDI são construidas dessa forma, inclusive eu mesmo já fiz, porém em projetos action-based onde não dependo do JSF eu faço o uso de DTO's assim com as interfaces do meu dominio, geralmente minhas aplicações tem 4 módulos seriam mais ou menos um EJB onde tem meus modelos, repositórios, e serviços um EJBClient que tem meus DTO's, interfaces @Local e objetos que servem ao módulo WEB(.war) e ao EJB(jar) e o .ear que nada mais é do que o pacote de todos módulos.

Comment: É claro que posso usar DTO's com faces também, porém os meus são imútaveis ou seja, não tenho métodos set e isso com faces não rola, mas curti sua pergunta, vou deixar o pessoal com bom embasamento tecnico em DDD comentar.

Comment: O problema eh fazer esse mapeamento na mão neh.. O risco de esquecer algo na manutenção eh enorme.. Eu n sei arriscaria fazer algo sem um automapper da vida

Comment: Mas usar dto na frente parece dificultar tanto a inserção de logica de negocio nos serviços... Na minha visão as entidades de domínio q deveriam vigorar em todas as regras dentro do dominio.

Comment: entendo, é que no meu caso minhas telas são complexas, outro dia estive conversando com um gringo extamente o que estamos falando agora, onde ele me disse que meus DTO's eram um anti-pattern (um hack para minhas views), na verdade eu curto o uso dos DTO's não só pela imutabilidade mas também porque não preciso expor várias entidades a view, tenho um objeto que pode servir a uma ou várias telas e pode ser formado de várias entidades, la no meu EJB eu faço uso de outros patterns como assemblers que fazem o trabalho sujo da conversão entidade x DTO, mas confesso que é um pouco complexo.

Comment: porém fica tudo muito separado.

Comment: Pze .tava lendo sobre assemblers tbm . vou respirar mais desse assunto p ver ser absorvo isso por osmose..  Tenho um brother q faz DDD c ASP NET e usa view model ..parece q vale a pena